# Route in Vue. The URL is refreshed, but the content of the login page is always consistent with the / page

Tags: vue.js, url, hyperlink, router

The program content is shown in the figure. The routing configuration file is in the index.js file in the route. As a result, the URL has changed, but the page has always been consistent with the root page. I tried many methods, and it took an afternoon to solve it.
I'm a beginner. I hope you don't laugh at me and can help me solve my problems. Thank you

app.vue:

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
     root组件
    <router-link to="/login"> to login</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

login.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        login组件
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style lang="less" scoped>

</style>
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import login from '../components/login.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/login' , compoment: login}

]

const router =  new VueRouter ({
  routes
})

export default router
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index.js'


import './plugins/element.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

File structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled word `component` in file `outer/index.js`.
Should be `{ path: '/login' , component: login}`

Comment: thank you! I solved the problem with your help! Thank you.